# jQuery - Hide element but maintain the space

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, visibility

Is there any thing similar to the css property and value **visibility: hidden** in jQuery? The hide function doesn't maintain the space.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the same effect as `visiblity: hidden`, then use that.

```
$('some selector').css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

Or set the opacity to zero, if you're looking for something that you can animate:

```
$('some selector').animate({'opacity': 0}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery is nothing more than a Javascript library, so if you know a way to do something with pure JS, then just do it. You don't have to rely on JQuery to do it. Both JS and JQuery have a way to get a DOM element and change its style attributes. Since Matt provided a JQuery answer, here is how it is done with pure Javascipt:

```
document.getElementById("id").style.visibility = "hidden";
```